# Why won't twitter use my coordinates?

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-oauth

I'm using the PHP twitteroauth library to post tweets to my account. I have latitude and longitude coordinates for each tweet (it's for a client who's walking solo to the North Pole so it's quite interesting).

Here's the call

```
$connection->post('statuses/update', array(
    "status"=> $tweet, 
    "lat"   => 51.527407,
    "long"  => -0.081566
));
```

The [API documentation](http://dev.twitter.com/doc/post/statuses/update) is wonderfully example free, making it a pure joy to work with, but I think that's right.

I've also made sure that I've allowed location tweets in my twitter settings, but still nothing.

I'm finding API documentation regarding [Locations](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/geo_dev_guidelines) is impenetrable.

You can see my ham-fisted attempts to get [this working here](http://twitter.com/#!/gargantuan)...

Can anyone point out what I'm overlooking?

Comment: It should work. Your account has geo enabled and the lat/long work as demoed [here](https://apigee.com/console/apigee-console-snapshots-1298955600000_0999fcee-daac-4077-a319-bd76b0c9b858/rendersnapshotview).

Comment: Could it be that I'm expecting something to happen that doesn't happen? I was expecting to see a map in the right hand panel. Also, are you the Abraham behind twitteroauth? If so, thanks for saving me a load of hard work already.

Comment: Your example should work. I don't see any reason why it shouldn't. My guess is maybe there is a bug somewhere that somehow keeping the lat/long from being sent to Twitter. Yep I'm that Abraham :) Glad you are getting use out of it.

Answer (score 3):

You should enable "display_coordinates" and "geo_enabled".

```
$post_status = $connection->post('statuses/update', array(                             
                                                'status' => YOUR_MESSAGE,                                        
                                                'lat' => YOUR_LATITUDE,                                 
                                                'long' => YOUR_LONGITUDE,                                        
                                                'display_coordinates' => 'true',                                    
                                                'geo_enabled' => 'true'
));
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you enable locations on the user's profile?

http://twitter.com/settings/account "Tweet Location"

Comment: It looks like geo is enabled for the account: https://api.twitter.com/1/users/show/gargantuan.json

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the Lat and Long need to be strings.

```
$connection->post('statuses/update', array(
    "status"=> $tweet, 
    "lat"   => "51.527407",
    "long"  => "-0.081566"
));
```

See it working [here](http://twitter.com/#!/gargantuan/status/46608904762818560)

I feel dumb for not trying that sooner. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Let me know, if its working in API console http://dev.twitter.com/console

Comment: Not sure what I'm meant to be doing with that. But looking at the tweets, the go bit comes out emptylike this: <geo/><coordinates/> but it's showing geoenabled to be true.